# Joomla 2.5 breadcrumb always shows "Home" Only

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a Joomla 2.5 site Multilingual site. But something wrong with the breadcrumb. It always shows only Home.

I set up joomla local copy without enabling multilingual feature and then breadcrumb works fine. So I suspect multilingual feature would be the problem. How do I resolve this issue ?

thank you very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted it out. In my site Main menu also has spanish equivalent menu. There for default home menu item set to English-menu  home. So I created another menu, didn't assigned any position .created menu item and set it to default home.

Then It gave me 404 in index page since default home set to nowhere. Then I selected my main menu(English) and click on "make default home" square on Home menu item. then Britain flag appeared.

Now breadcrumb is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are different possible causes for this issue, but I would first try to disable cache for the breadcrumbs module:

Extensions -> Module Manager -> Breadcrumbs -> Advanced Options -> Caching -> None